# Arrange items in an array by the time they were added to that array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Basically I have a Collection model and a Post model, where a Collection has many posts and a Post belongs to many collections. So I'll occasionally push posts to the `@collection.posts` array using `<<`, to replicate a post being *added* to a collection. Now is there a way to order the posts in `@collection.posts` by the time they were pushed to that array? If yes, how?

All relevant models:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :collectables
  has_many :collections, through: :collectables
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :collectables
  has_many :posts, through: :collectables
end
```

**collectable.rb**

```
class Collectable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

Comment: How does your join table look like? Has it only the two columns `collection_id` and `post_id`? Or does it have other columns, like `created_at`?

Comment: @spickermann I actually asked a more detailed question about it here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188708/controller-action-for-adding-a-post-to-a-collection-model-rails but I figured no one responded to it as it was too long. So I decided to ask a more to-the-point question. Nonetheless, I just updated this question with all the relevant model codes

Comment: What columns does your `collectables` database table have?

Comment: @spickermann The columns are `post_id`, `collection_id`, `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: This sound like a conceptual question with rails. You need to use in - memory storage. Whether or not you use the session or database to do this depends on if this data needs to persist across multiple requests or not.

Comment: How do you want them to be arranged? On the time they get added(which is a default behavior you have currently) or based on some position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess adding an order scope to the definition of the association would work:

```
# in collection.rb
has_many :posts,
         -> { order('collectables.created_at DESC') },
         through: :collectables
```

Comment: Doh! That was simple. I didn't even know association definitions accepted scopes. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why not simply order by ID?

Comment: @Ven : Because `collectables` table doesn't have an `id` (according to the OP's comment above). And the `post_id` or `collection_id` are not necessarily in the same order than the date of adding a post to a collection.